# GitHub SSH Config: "Bad configuration option: IdentifyFile"

Tags: github, ssh, config

I'm trying to create a .ssh/config file for multiple SSH accounts (specifically for github.com).  I've tried several tutorials and github help walk-throughs but nothing seems to work.

I created a `id_rsa_test` and `id_rsa_test.pub`.  I uploaded `id_rsa_test.pub` to github.

I then created a `~/.ssh/config` file with the following:

```
# github account
Host github.com-test github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User git 
    IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test
```

and

```
# github account
Host github.com-test github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User git 
    IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test.pub
```

I then try several commands.  i.e.:

```
git clone git@github-test:username/my_project.git

git push
```

...everytime I get the following error:

```
/home/username/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: IdentifyFile
/home/username/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: YOUR AMAZING! The one thing I forgot was the **IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test.pub** thank you! **EVERYONE** don't forget the **.pub** as well.

Comment: @wesleyfranks No, there must **not** be a ".pub" suffix in the IdentityFile line (that results in one of the following errors: *"WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!"*, or *"Load key "xxx.pub": invalid format"*).

Comment: DONT ADD .PUB
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48330113/8333806

Answer (score 320, accepted):

It is Identi**t**yFile with a 't', not Identi**f**yFile.

Comment: May be the biggest cut-n-paste #snafu in the history of computers

Comment: Thank you so much! Made a similar mistake: `IntentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. I can't type.